# currentBuild.result null on master

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to send a Slack message when the build succeeds/fails through a scripted Jenkins pipeline, but I have noticed that `currentBuild.result` is `null` on `master` branch for some reason. Is there a better way to do this?

```
try {
    //pipline code
} finally {
    branch_name = env.BRANCH_NAME
    if (branch_name == 'master') {
        message_body = """"""
        if (currentBuild.result == 'SUCCESS') {
            message_body = """:green_check: Build succeeded for `$branch_name`. See $env.BUILD_URL for details"""
        }
        if (currentBuild.result == 'FAILURE') {
            message_body = """:red_x: Build failed for `$branch_name`. See $env.BUILD_URL for details"""
        }
        if (message_body != '') {
            slackSend(channel: "#channel", message: message_body.stripIndent().trim())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using declarative or scripted pipelines?
There are some differences between `currentBuild.result`and `currentBuild.currentResult`. See [here](https://shenxianpeng.github.io/2021/01/result-vs-currentresult/)

The best way is to use a post condition.

Comment: I am using scripted. I have noticed that `currentBuild.currentResult` is always "SUCCESS" even when the build has failed.

Comment: Its because the lifecycle has not set the result before you ask for. So the best way is to set the build result by condition your self.